# The Rows Holding the Group-wise Maximum of a Certain Column (how to kill duplicates...)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've asked similar question earlier, but this similarity is superficial, the problem lies somewhere deeper...

So consider the following MS SQL Server 2008 table:

```
  ID  |   X   |   Y
------+-------+-------
   1  |   1   |   1
   2  |   1   |   2
   3  |   1   |   2
   4  |   1   |   3
   5  |   1   |   3
   6  |   2   |   4
   7  |   2   |   5
   8  |   2   |   5
   9  |   2   |   5
  10  |   3   |   1
  11  |   3   |   10
  12  |   3   |   10
```

I need to receive ONE of the following results (doesn't really matter which it would be):

```
  ID  |   X   |   Y
------+-------+-------
   4  |   1   |   3
   7  |   2   |   5
  11  |   3   |   10
```

Or

```
  ID  |   X   |   Y
------+-------+-------
!! 5  |   1   |   3
   7  |   2   |   5
  11  |   3   |   10
```

Or

```
.....
```

Or

```
  ID  |   X   |   Y
------+-------+-------
   5  |   1   |   3
   9  |   2   |   5
  12  |   3   |   10
```

I need to

1. Group table by X
2. Select the maximum Y
3. Select the ID of that maximum Y
4. The result should also be grouped by X

There shouldn't be results like:

```
  ID  |   X   |   Y
------+-------+-------
   4  |   1   |   3
   5  |   1   |   3
   7  |   2   |   5
   8  |   2   |   5
   9  |   2   |   5
  11  |   3   |   10
  12  |   3   |   10
```

Comment: If you've already got SQL to produce that final table, it's trivially easy to wrap that in `SELECT MIN(ID),X,Y FROM (<existing query>) T GROUP BY X,Y`, to get your first "desired" result. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE (ID INTEGER, X INTEGER, Y INTEGER)
INSERT @Data VALUES (1,1,1),(2,1,2),(3,1,2),(4,1,3),(5,1,3),
    (6,2,4),(7,2,5),(8,2,5),(9,2,5),(10,3,1),(11,3,10),(12,3,10)

;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT ID, X, Y, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY X ORDER BY Y DESC, ID ASC) AS RowNo
FROM @Data
)

SELECT ID, X, Y FROM CTE WHERE RowNo = 1
```

So, using [ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx) to assign each row an incremental number which resets to 1 for each new X value. For rows with the same value for X, the row number is assigned incrementally ordered by Y DESCENDING and ID ASCENDING - so for a particular X value, row number 1 will be assigned to the one with the HIGHEST Y value and the LOWEST ID value. We then add a restriction to only return those where RowNo is 1.

Comment: Just updated my answer to link to ROW_NUMBER() reference. There's an MSDN reference for OVER: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461(v=SQL.100).aspx

Comment: @Denis: you can also look at the **"Related"** questions, in this page, on the right **================>**

Comment: Is it possible to use this construct inside nested query? I need to do something like INSERT INTO .. SELECT ...

Comment: Yes. You can use the CTE as above, then just do: INSERT INTO...SELECT...FROM CTE WHERE RowNo = 1. Or, you don't actually need to use the CTE at all - you could wrap the ROW_NUMBER select as a subquery

Answer (score 2):

This will bring the first row for each duplicate combination of x,y

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tablename t1
INNER JOIN
(SELECT MIN(id) id FROM tablename GROUP BY X,Y HAVING COUNT(*)>1)
 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Testing the code got the following result:

```
ID  X   Y   
2   1   2   
4   1   3   
7   2   5   
11  3   10
```

Comment: Great it also worked! Unfortunately this solution will force me using temporary tables because I'm selecting from tablename twice... From other point of view it uses standard constructs and therefore more compatible...

Comment: Better to have two options than nothing! Nice to know i have helped.

Comment: @Denis: Note that this answer is different than AdaTheDev's one (will give different results). Which of the two you need, is not entirely clear.

Comment: You are right, I can tell for sure that duplicates in X column are bad for me... So it's AdaTheDev's solution is more suitable for me, thank you

Comment: Then in the nested query group only by Y instead of X,Y

Answer (score 1):

There is one more elegant solution for such a type of tasks:

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE (ID INTEGER, X INTEGER, Y INTEGER);

INSERT @Data VALUES (1,1,1);
INSERT @Data VALUES (2,1,2);
INSERT @Data VALUES (3,1,2);
INSERT @Data VALUES (4,1,3);
INSERT @Data VALUES (5,1,3);
INSERT @Data VALUES (6,2,4);
INSERT @Data VALUES (7,2,5);
INSERT @Data VALUES (8,2,5);
INSERT @Data VALUES (9,2,5);
INSERT @Data VALUES (10,3,1);
INSERT @Data VALUES (11,3,10);
INSERT @Data VALUES (12,3,10);

SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES 
    ID, X, Y
FROM @Data
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY X ORDER BY Y DESC, ID ASC);
```