# VLOOKUP style lookup in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table of data which stores prices for different commodities on different dates.

```
CREATE TABLE COMMODITIES(
    [MARKET_DATE] [datetime2](0) NOT NULL,
    [THE_TYPE] [numeric](2, 0) NOT NULL,
    [CLOSE_VALUE] [numeric](10, 4) NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

`MARKET_DATE` holds the trading date (the dates are in ascending order, but non-sequential)

`CLOSE_VALUE` holds the price

`THE_TYPE` holds the type of commodity.

The trading dates for each commodity are different.

---

I need to get a list of all dates where `THE_TYPE`=1, with the price, as well as the corresponding price for the commodity with `THE_TYPE`=2

---

If the trading dates for each commodity were the same I could do a simple join (equivalent to the Excel `VLOOKUP (, false)`

```
SELECT mr1.market_date
    ,mr1.close_value,mr2.close_value

FROM commodities mr1
LEFT JOIN commodities  mr2 ON mr1.market_date = mr2.market_date
    AND mr2.the_type = 2
WHERE mr1.the_type = 1
```

---

However because the trading dates are not the same, I need to look for the a non-exact match equivalent to the Excel `VLOOKUP (, true)` - i.e. the maximum date in `mr2` which is on or before `mr1.market_date`

---

I am looking for a neat solution. I could as a workaround enter the intervening dates into the database which would work. Or alternatively I could do the following

```
SELECT mr1.market_date
    ,mr1.close_value
    , 

            (SELECT top 1 close_value
            FROM commodities mr2

            where mr2.market_date <= mr1.market_date
                AND mr2.the_type = 2
                order by market_date desc
            ) AS close_value

FROM commodities mr1
WHERE mr1.the_type = 1
```

but I hope there is a neater (and quicker) solution

---

As an example, if the table holds the following

```
MARKET_DATE CLOSE_VALUE  THE_TYPE
    2012-01-01  300  1
    2012-01-03  310  1
    2012-01-05  310  1
    2012-01-01  400  2
    2012-01-02  420  2
    2012-01-05  430  2
```

I would get

```
2012-01-01  300  400
2012-01-03  310  420
2012-01-05  310  430
```

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? Can you post a small input as well as example of expected output?

Comment: you could move the (select ...) as close_value to an inner join. But I doubt it will make such a difference in the execution time

Comment: To shahkalpesh. See updated question for an example

Comment: It looks like you are trying to do a groupwise maximum. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452284/the-rows-holding-the-group-wise-maximum-of-a-certain-column-how-to-kill-duplica

Comment: I think that the correlated subquery is a good solution. Alternatively, you could write that as an `OUTER APPLY` for better readability

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use CROSS APPLY. It might be slightly faster but probably not noticeable for this case:

```
SELECT mr1.market_date
    ,mr1.close_value as close_value_1
    ,p.close_value as close_value_2
FROM commodities mr1
cross apply
  (SELECT top 1 close_value
        FROM commodities mr2
        where mr2.market_date <= mr1.market_date
            AND mr2.the_type = 2
            order by market_date desc) p
  WHERE mr1.the_type = 1
```

See it in [action](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1671b/12)

Comment: +1 for introducing me to SQLFiddle, will get a lot of use out of that. The solution also works as well :P

Comment: Thanks - this works, but as you predicted I only got a marginal speed increase (18 seconds instead of 19 seconds) My case involves a table with about 40,000 rows with the cross-apply/sub-query applied about 10 times (I presented the simplified case in my question)

Comment: I would try that as max(close_value) without the order by

Comment: Thanks Blam, but I need the close_value of the maximum date, rather than the maximum close_value

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH OrderedOrders AS
(
    SELECT mr1.market_date
          ,mr1.close_value as mr1close
          ,mr2.close_value as mr2close
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY mr1.market_date ORDER BY mr2.market_date desc) AS RowNumber
    FROM commodities mr1
    JOIN commodities mr2
      ON mr2.market_date <= mr1.market_date
     AND mr2.the_type = 2
     AND mr1.the_type = 1 
)  
SELECT market_date, mr1close, mr2close  
FROM OrderedOrders 
WHERE RowNumber = 1
```

Comment: This doesn't make sure that the value chosen is the one with the closest date, just the `max` one

Comment: @Lamak If you take the Max of mr2.market_date <= mr1.market_date then how is that not the closest date?    Same thing the sub query is doing.

Comment: From what I see, you are taking the max `close_value`, nothing to do with the max date where `mr2.market_date <= mr1.market_date`

Comment: Thanks! BTW there is a small typo "PARTITION" should be "PARTITION BY"

Comment: Thanks very much for this. It does seem elegant, but for me works quite slowly, especially if I need to apply to a second or third table.

Comment: Look at the query plan.  If you have some loops going on an innner merge or inner hash join my help.  Or an apply might be the best.

Comment: Also type as tinyint (or smallint) would be a little faster.  smalldatetime would be a little faster.  Indexes?

Comment: To Blam. Thanks very much for the suggestions... As I did have a working solution, unfortunately I did not have the resources to try and tweak your solution...